# How to pass argument from template to view in Flask

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have template which is doing some operations on fields of table:

```html
<tr>
    {% for field in row %}
        {% if field is link_field %}
            <td><a href="{{ url_for('munin') }}">{{ field | table_field | safe }}</a></td>
        {% else %}
            <td>{{ field | table_field | safe }}</td>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
```

To my view:

```
@app.route("/munin")
def munin(field):
        return redirect("http://{0}/munin".format(field))
```

I would like to send field from templates.

The whole idea is, to make some fields in the table as a hyperlink to an external site, when the address http of those hyperlinks are attributes of a field (e.g. ip address).

I have tried to do this:

```html
<tr>
    {% for field in row %}
        {% if field is link_field %}
            <td><a href="{{ url_for('munin', field=field) }}">{{ field | table_field | safe }}</a></td>
        {% else %}
            <td>{{ field | table_field | safe }}</td>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
```

But instead of sending me to site:

```
http://field/munin
```

it is sending me to:

```
http://mysite/munin?field=field
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your route configuration doesn't handle any `field` parameter. Adjust your route:

```
@app.route("/munin/<field>")
def munin(field):
    return redirect("http://{0}/munin".format(field))
```

to accept path paramaters.

Comment: Wow, why i'm so stupid? Thanks, that solve everything.

Answer (score 1):

```
from flask import request
field = request.args.get('field')
```

Did the job.